# Pully rig hook release problem

Tags: fishing, beach

So I'm still learning about beach fishing and trying different rigs. Been using the pully rig on one rod with big baits (bluey, squid/worm wraps etc) and now and again on the cast the hook releases from the breakaway lead clip on the cast. Changed over to an " imp" I think it's called with the plastic clip and same thing happened on a few occasions. Anybody suggest ways of stopping this or what maybe causing it? 
Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Some photos may help if you're unsure on the name of something.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. I'll try to upload it as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome Edward Kelly! We've had some changes to our photo posting system lately, so if you happen to have any problem, let us know! Either way, we look forward to seeing what you have and trying to help you!